# Trying to install android-tools-adb and getting unable to locate package

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, repository, adb

I wasn't able to install these packages when I used

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

I get

```
unable to locate package android-tools-adb
```

Can you help, please?

Comment: The package should be located in the universe collections of Ubuntu.  Check your `software & updates` to ensure that the 'community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)' collection is checked, and then perform `sudo apt-get update` and try to re-install.

Answer (score 9):

Don't know why this hadn't been put as an answer, I just put it here from Charles Green excellent comment.

`android-tools-adb` and `android-tools-fastboot` are in the **universe** repository.
You can enable it in [Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/a/148645/573767) or just hit this one-liner which will enable and install everything.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to slightly tweak the suggested command from Suncatcher.  The following worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && android-tools-fastboot
```

and then use:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can manually download and install it via a deb file from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/android-tools-adb/download).

Comment: The link is dead.